# Compact operator on invariant subspace is compact

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Statement:** Let $T \in \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$, where $T$ is a compact operator. Let $M$ be a closed invariant subspace of $T$. Show that the restriction of $T$ to $M$ is compact.

**Attempted Proof:** Let $\{m_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence in $M$. Since $T$ is compact it contains a convergent subsequence $T(m_{n_k}) \rightarrow \mu$. Now since $M$ is closed and invariant under $T$ it contains all of its limit points, so $\mu \in M$. Hence we are compact.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Looks good to me. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390580/is-restriction-of-compact-operator-always-compact) is a related thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is good. However, the phrasing can be improved a little. 
For example, instead of "Since $T$ is compact *it* contains a convergent..."
we have to replace "it" by "the sequence $\{T(m_n)\}$".

At the end, instead of saying "*we* are compact", maybe we could replace "we" by "the restriction of $T$ to $M$".